Is it possible to use unweighted Kappa for some questions and weighted for others to measure interrater agreement in the same questionnaire?
I intend to conduct an interrater agreement analysis on a questionnaire about student essays that contains binary options, mainly yes-no questions, ordinal variables, primarily a likert agreement scale, and one or two unordered categorical variables. On the basis of what I have read on the suitability of weighted and standard unweighted Kappa for different question types, I would like to do the following: use standard Kappa for the binary questions and the unordered categorical variables and weighted Kappa for the ordinal variables. Is it possible to use the two types of Kappa inside the same questionnaire? Ideally, I would like to do count agreement automatically, e.g. using Google Forms or Microsoft Forms. Would there be a way of setting out the questionnaire so that the binary and unordered categorical variable questions are counted in one block and questions with ordinal variables in another? If so, would you recommend setting out the questionnaire in this way and using  standard Kappa for the first block and weighted Kappa for the second? If need be, I could carry out the interrater agreement manually as there will not be a huge amount of questionnaire data to analyse. If so, would you support the use of standard kappa for one set of questions and weighted for the other? The final factor to bear in mind is that there will only be two raters per essay.
